# Print the return value of user-defined function

Tags: function, t-sql, return-value

I simply want to do this something like this for testing the function:

```
PRINT fnctGeneric([argument])
```

I've searched around but can't find anything. Tried https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=SQL+Print+function+return+value **--**
https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=SQL+Print+return+value+from+user-defined+function **--**
https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=SQL+Print+return+value+from+function

and searched on stack

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Print+return+value+of+function+SQL

but haven't found anything.

I'd have thought this would be easy, so easy to find, but it's not, so I can only assume I'm missing something.

So my question is how do you simply print the return value of a function? Do I need to store the value, in a variable say, before printing it?

Can't Do this:

```
DECLARE @Return AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Return = fnctCalculateCertName(4471)
PRINT @Return
```

Because of this

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 205
>   'fnctCalculateCertName' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Can't do my first attempt:

```
PRINT fnctCalculateCertName(4471)
```

again because of the same error. Can't do this:

```
SELECT fnctCalculateCertName(4471) FROM system
```

Or this:

```
DECLARE @Return AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Return = fnctCalculateCertName(4471) FROM system
PRINT @Return
```

I can't believe it's so difficult to print the results of a function like this :/

And it's definitely in my database, I can see it in the Scalar-valued Functions tab

Comment: It sounds like you have an issue with your function. Have you checked if the function even exists? And have you tried adding the schema like "dbo.fnctCalculateCertName"?

Comment: You need to add the schema, when calling functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the schema, when calling functions:

```
PRINT dbo.fnctGeneric([argument])
```

Comment: Wow. I knew I was missing something :( My head might literally explode.

Comment: WHY? WHY, WHY, WHY, WHY, WHY. Why do functions REQUIRE Schema while most others don't? DAMN YOU MICROSOFT

Comment: I would say something not suitable for work, but since I'm at work, that wouldn't be suitable.

Comment: At least there was an easy solution :)

Comment: That almost makes it worse. Spending collectivity almost an hour trying to do this when I needed just four more characters makes me die inside just a little.

Comment: Well at least this shan't be a lesson I forget in haste

Comment: We've all been there the first time we used functions